# How to set the KeyListener for Canvas.KEY_NUM2 in CodeNameOne

Tags: java-me, lwuit, codenameone

I had this code in LWUIT, but now that I've migrated to CodeNameOne the Canvas class not have the constants KEY_NUM1, KEY_NUM2, etc. And I can't add the Key Listener.

form.addKeyListener (Canvas.KEY_NUM1, bListener);

Where can I find these constants in CodeNameOne?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `'0'` instead of the num1 constant.